# Using inotify to check for directory modifications

Tags: bash, inotify

I'm getting started to bash scripts and I am making a script that backs up a directory on any modifications. Modification includes new files/folders and modifications to existing files. ow would I go about doing this using inotify ?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code ? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the tool `inotifywait`.

For example:

```
inotifywait -r -m -e modify -e create <one_or_more_dirs> |
while read line
do
     echo $line
done
```